# Gitignore not ignoring files

Tags: git, gitignore

For some reasons gitignore is working,
I've created a new folder and initialized git init
created a .gitignore file and added some files to ignore but it's not ignoring am I missing something?

before this i was still facing this problem in the previous repo that time i tried some solutions including

```
git rm --cached filename
```

because that time those files were on the remote repo i did `--cached rm` but still didnt work after this, to be sure if there's any bug of sort i've created a new project but it's still happening it's not ignoring the files

here's the snapshot of the whole folder even vscode is showing that the files have updated

[image]

also, .git/info/exclude worked but it's not working if the file is in a subdirectory

Comment: "those files were on the remote repo" - is this a new repo or a cloned one?

Comment: that was a different repo this one is different and both are on main

Comment: If those three files exist in your repo, the `.gitignore` will have no effect on that. It tells Git to ignore untracked files that have been added locally. But tracked files cannot be ignored by this mechanism. You first have to remove them: `git rm --cached a.txt` then `git commit -m"Removing a.txt"` and now, since `a.txt` is no longer tracked on the current commit, the `.gitignore` should be effective.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR** I think you just forgot to commit the results of your `git rm --cached` command.

**Details**

If those three files exist in your repo, the `.gitignore` will have no effect on that. It tells Git to ignore untracked files that have been added locally. But tracked files cannot be ignored by this mechanism.

You first have to remove them, as you tried to do:

```
git rm --cached filename
```

then you have to commit those changes, because what's in the cache is not effective yet:

```
git commit -m"Removing filename"
```

and now, since `filename` is no longer tracked on the current commit/branch, the `.gitignore` should be effective.

**Caveat - do you really want to delete the file?**

Now, do you really want to remove these files on the remote repo too? If so, this is the right solution.

But if you don't want to remove those files on the remote repo, this is not the way to go. What you need instead is `git update-index --assume-unchanged filename` to tell your local sandbox that you don't want to track any changes you make locally to this file that should otherwise remain tracked.